# Is Temporary Data on the Stack Always Preset?

Tags: c, stack

Using this example code:

```
int32_t main()
{
    uint32_t temp = get_value();
    if(temp > 0)
    {
        some_function();
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        run();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming `temp` is stored on the stack and not in a register, are modern C compilers smart enough to know `temp` is used only once during initialization? Will the 4 bytes of space it uses on the stack be reused later during execution?

Comment: FWIW, you can "guarantee" that the optimization will happen by using `if(get_value() > 0)`

Comment: *Assuming `temp` is stored on the stack and not in a register,* - why would you assume that? This is exactly the optimization you want here. The function `get_value()` will place the return value in the register according to ABI (unless it is some weird ABI which does not do it), and the compiler will reuse this register to check for the branch condition.

Comment: If it does store it on the stack (eg you mark it `volatile`) it will never go away (that is, until the function finishes which will only happen when the program finishes). This is a GOOD thing.

Comment: As for assuming `temp` is stored on the stack, for a real program I notice that when compiled with maximum optimization, the entire initialization routine is inlined. The routine uses many large structs that don't fit in a register.
This caused me to question whether all of that data was needlessly taking up stack space forever.

Comment: What answer do you expect? Every implementation is free to do it one way or the other, as long as the observable program behavior is standard conforming.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the 4 bytes of space it uses on the <strike>stack</strike> *anywhere* be reused later during execution?

Perhaps (as it is not later used), it is implementation defined.

---

To insure `temp` space allowed to be available in the `for` loop, create a `{}` block:

```
int32_t main() {
  { // add
    uint32_t temp = get_value();
    if(temp > 0) {
      some_function();
    }
  } // add
  
  // `temp` out of scope
  for(;;) {
    run();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But beware of premature optimization.  Typically more useful to spend time on other space/memory saving techniques.